# Building your own Onavo

Tags: proxy, iphone, profile

[Onavo](http://www.onavo.com), an app for iPhone and Android, is a pretty interesting peice of software. It uses (on the iPhone anyway, not sure about Android) a custom profile, which re-routes your traffic though the Onavo server. Their server is a Proxy Server, which does some compression of HTML, images, and some other things...

Anyway, what i want to know is, is it posible to build your own? how do you get the iPhone to use your own server as a proxy? it seems to the this magic profile which does the major work. For Vodafone Ireland (my current provider) there is no setting to change how the connection is set, but Onavo have managed it... I would like to be able to use this to monitor my own data transfer, maybe do some compression, etc...

[Updated since getting down voted: How do i get the iPhone to use my own Proxy?]

Comment: You should ask the Updated question on [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can build your own. They built their own, right?

Comment: thats not the question... how do you build your own? how do i get the iPhone to use my proxy?

Comment: You said "Anyway, what i want to know is, is it posible to build your own?" that sure sounds like a question to me. It's off topic anyway. That's development related, not Sysadmin related.